# Biztalk - processing a flat file receives "no subscribers found" message

Tags: biztalk, flat-file, biztalk2006r2, receive-location

I've created a flat file schema in Visual Studio from an instance of a CSV file I have, and it validates fine, and I've hooked up an orchestration to send and receive ports set to expect a file of that schema. When I publish the orchestration and use it to pick up a file, it's immediately suspended, with the following error:

> The published message could not be
>   routed because no subscribers were
>   found. This error occurs if the
>   subscribing orchestration or send port
>   has not been enlisted, or if some of
>   the message properties necessary for
>   subscription evaluation have not been
>   promoted. Please use the Biztalk
>   Administration console to troubleshoot
>   this failure.

The send port is enlisted, and since I'm not doing any processing based on the contents, I don't think I need to promote anything. I'm currently using the PassthroughReceive pipeline - the other three pipelines I have give me errors about not being able to disassemble the file, as it seems they're expecting XML.

Am I missing something obvious here? Or, in other words:

> Can I pass the contents of a CSV file
>   to my orchestration without a custom
>   pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when you create a custom flat file schema, you need to create a custom pipeline (a receive pipeline in this case), add the FlatFile Disassembler component to it and then configure its properties with your custom flat file schema.

Then you need to configure your receive port to use this receive pipeline.