# No subscribers were found on send port

Tags: biztalk

I have an issue with send port:

> The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found. This error occurs if the subscribing orchestration or send port has not been enlisted, or if some of the message properties necessary for subscription evaluation have not been promoted.

But this send port sent messages successfully but then I still see this message in Suspended.

Any ideas how is it possible?

Comment: The message that you are trying to publish to the message box does not match the filter on the send port or an orchestration.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049244/the-published-message-could-not-be-routed-because-no-subscribers-were-found?rq=1 for example

Comment: So it isn't saying that there isn't a subscription on the send port, it is saying your message doesn't match any subscription on anything.   Another example  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521338/biztalk-processing-a-flat-file-receives-no-subscribers-found-message?rq=1  If you need more help, you are going to have to give more details.  e.g. how are you publishing the message (Receive Location&Port or Orchestration), the context properties of the message, and the binding / filter on the send port.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't saying that there isn't a subscription on the send port, it is saying your message doesn't match any subscription on anything.

You need to check the context properties on the suspended message and compare it to the subscription on the send port you expect the message to go to.  You will find that they do not match.